# Проблема с установкой плагинов

Tags: vim, php, debian, linux

Нашел статью по настройке Vim'а для php. Как там написано, плагины (файлы с форматом `*.vim`) нужно поместить в папку

```
~/.vim/plugin
```

У меня такой папки не оказалось. Каталог с плагинами vim'a оказался таким:

```
/usr/share/vim/addons/plugin
```

Я скачал `NERD Tree` (плагин для vim), скопировал его в этот каталог. Дальше запустил Vim а там ничего не изменилось. Подскажите в чем проблема? Может я что не так делаю или что нажать нужно? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте занести его в /usr/share/vim/vimXX/plugin, где XX -- номер версии вашего редактора. А лучше сделайте, как рекомендовано. ~/.vim -- каталог, где хранятся файлы vim лично для вас, как конкретного пользователя. Соответственно ~/.vim/plugin -- установленные лично для вас плагины, а ~/.vim/doc -- ваш хелп. Ну и можно в добавок `:helptags ~/.vim/doc` для создания тегов для вашего NERD_tree.txt.

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня нет каталога ~/.vim

Comment: Неожиданно для себя нашел его в каталоге рута. В домашнем каталоге его нет. Скопировал плагин в указанную директорию (~/.vim/plugin), запустил vim, но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Прописал в конце NERD_tree.vim такую строку:

call s:initNerdTree(getcwd())

Все запустилось:-)
Ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Но к этому времени уже был ответ @chernomyrdin, где последовательность действий просто расписана.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы пользуетесь пакетным менеджером (то есть vim ставите из пакетов) то совершенно точно не стоит класть личные plugin в системные каталоги. Если у вас нету ~/.vim/plugin - создайте его, так как vim не создает эти каталоги. То есть вам необходимо сделать:

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/plugin ~/.vim/doc
cp plugin/NERD_tree.vim ~/.vim/plugin/
cp doc/NERD_tree.txt ~/.vim/doc/
```

Answer (score 2):

Наверное для Вас лучший вариант - взять готовый инструмент, который сам установит все плагины и в будущем будет их обновлять.
Я лично использую [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle).  На этой странице подробно описано как его установить и как прописывать плагины. А он сам скачает, установит и настроит.